# Analyzing the encoding of a DFA by a deterministic Turing machine

Tags: turing-machines, computability, finite-automata

Define $L=\{\langle D,R \rangle \mid D$ is a DFA, $R$ is a regular expression, $L(D)=L(R) \}$

Is $L$ decidable?

Is $L$ decidable in polynomial time ($L \in P$)?

I am trying to ask: can a TM analyze a DFA encoding to output with a regular expression encoding on its tape and how fast can it be done?

Comment: You can just return $D$ itself. Can you try to make your problem more precise?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus thanks! I didn't realize $D$ itself works, I edited the question, please let me know if it still unclear

Comment: It’s still very imprecise. You seem to dislike DFAs, but you’re not explaining why, so it’s hard to make it more precise.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I think this edit is well-defined

Comment: Your problem is decidable. It’s a routine exercise in automata theory.

Comment: What about running time? can it be done in polynomial time? I mean, is this problem in $P$? Thanks.

Comment: Deciding whether a regular expression accepts all strings is already coNP-hard.

Comment: You are saying $L \in coNP-hard$? I can't see it trivially